# I want to find a computer language that has a common name

Tags: search, programming-languages

About 10 years ago, I was using a computer language called INFO on an ancient Prime.  It was a funky, but oddly useful language, and I'd like to find out more about it.  For instance, can I get a copy that would run on a PC?  However, if I google for "INFO" and "Computer Language," I'm not going to find it.  I've tried.  I think the company that created it was in the UK.

It was so easy to learn, that I was programming the first day, and yet was capable of true oddness.  The programs had line numbers, and if the numbers started with an odd number, the commands were SQL like and worked on the entire set.  If they started with an even number, the commands were a block that dealt with each item in the set one at a time.

So, a simple type of program could be something like this (I don't recall the syntax either)

```
100  select * from user_table
110  join with address_table
120  exclude duplicate addresses
200  for each record in set
205    print firstname, lastname
210    print addressLine1
220    print City, State, Zip
300  display "address labels printed"
```

It was capable of quick and impressive applications, that were almost simple to understand, and yet had a sneaky power that I was only beginning to understand after two years at the job.

How do I find it?  Can I get a copy that will work on a PC?

Comment: Sure it's not http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informix-4GL ? It has embedded SQL, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that's the Pr1me Information language; it's now hiding out in [IBM Universe](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/u2/universe/).  It was a competitor for [Pick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick_operating_system).

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct name was "Prime Information". Searching for that phrase might get you some slightly more relevant results.

You can find some info [here](http://www.malch.com/prime/primefaq.htm#L2_27).